# InactiveScopeException After Installing FOSCommentBundle

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3, foscommentbundle

I am setting up FOSCommentBundle, I followed all steps to install it however any page I access now, I am getting the exception below:

```
InactiveScopeException: You cannot create a service
("fos_comment.listener.thread_permalink") of an inactive scope ("request").
in C:\htdocs\click-na-ilha\app\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 1595
at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getFosComment_Listener_ThreadPermalinkService() in C:\htdocs\click-na-ilha\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 1904
at Container->get('fos_comment.listener.thread_permalink') in C:\htdocs\click-na-ilha\app\cache\dev\classes.php line 1772
at ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->lazyLoad('fos_comment.thread.create') in C:\htdocs\click-na-ilha\app\cache\dev\classes.php line 1737
at ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->getListeners(null) in C:\htdocs\click-na-ilha\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher.php line 107
at TraceableEventDispatcher->getListeners() in C:\htdocs\click-na-ilha\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher.php line 168
at TraceableEventDispatcher->getNotCalledListeners() in C:\htdocs\click-na-ilha\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher.php line 354
at TraceableEventDispatcher->saveInfoInProfile(object(Profile), false) in C:\htdocs\click-na-ilha\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher.php line 328
at TraceableEventDispatcher->updateProfiles('05b179', false) in C:\htdocs\click-na-ilha\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher.php line 431
at TraceableEventDispatcher->postDispatch('kernel.terminate', object(PostResponseEvent)) in C:\htdocs\click-na-ilha\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher.php line 148
at TraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.terminate', object(PostResponseEvent)) in C:\htdocs\click-na-ilha\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 2758
at HttpKernel->terminate(object(Request), object(Response)) in C:\htdocs\click-na-ilha\app\bootstrap.php.cache line 2159
at Kernel->terminate(object(Request), object(Response)) in C:\htdocs\click-na-ilha\web\app_dev.php line 32
```

Here is the code I have added https://gist.github.com/dextervip/3d9efe24c7241a6eeda0

What's wrong?

Comment: I have the same exception after upgrading Symfony from 2.1 to 2.2. That happens when built-in debug toolbar tries to collect all not called listeners (on kernel.terminate event), it initialize every not called listener for container's scope 'request', but scope 'request' is not active anymore on termination stage. I can't find proper way to fix that.